# SassError: Undefined mixin from "@include icon-button.core-styles;" following Material Design Top App Bar documentation

Tags: webpack, sass, material-design

After following the [Material Design Top App Bar](https://m2.material.io/components/app-bars-top/web#using-the-top-app-bar) documentation for scss, I could not build my scss with webpack.
I can't seem to include icon-button.core-styles in my scss. IntelliJ also says "Cannot find mixin 'core-styles' " on my styles.scss.

**Error message**

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
6 │ @include icon-button.core-styles;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 6:1  root stylesheet
SassError: SassError: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
6 │ @include icon-button.core-styles;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 6:1  root stylesheet
    at Object.loader (D:\...\webpack\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:69:14)

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 1615 ms
```

**src/styles.scss**

```scss
@use "@material/icon-button";
@use '@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar';
@use "@material/icon-button/styles";


@include icon-button.core-styles;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        // index: './src/_index.ts',
        styles: './src/styles.scss',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', 'scss'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './../public/dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'file-loader', options: {name: '[name].css'}},
                    {loader: 'extract-loader'},
                    {loader: 'css-loader'},
                    {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {postcssOptions: {plugins: [autoprefixer()]}}},
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {/* Prefer Dart Sass*/
                            implementation: require('sass'), /* See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804*/
                            webpackImporter: false,
                            sassOptions: {includePaths: ['./node_modules']},
                        },
                    }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material/icon-button": "^14.0.0",
    "@material/top-app-bar": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
@include icon-button.core-styles;
```

Should be replaced with

```
@import "@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button";
```

Source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/6169